# How to specify the position of a menu item without using id in Sublimes Text2

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to have a top level "Run" menu that will invoke "build" command for Sublime Text2 so that it kind of behave like a "run" button (instead of Ctrl+B) and I want to have it between Preferences and Help.

I could achieve this if I directly edit Packages\Default\Main.sublime-menu and insert the run menu between them like below:

```
    }, # end of "Preferences"

   {
        "caption": "Run",
        "command": "build"
    },

    {
        "caption": "Help",
```

But I don't know if that's a good way because the next update may overwrite the default setting. Ideally, I want to define this in a separate file.

The normal way of specifying the menu position is 'id'. But this works only when I need to add a submenu to an existing one as `children`.

So, how do I specify the position in between Preferences and Help without messing with the default sublime-menu file?

Answer (score 2):

By putting a dummy entry with empty list `[]` as children into `Preferences`, I could move the cursor to `Preferences` so that the next menu entry would come after it on the right.

```
[   
    {

        "caption": "Preferences",
        "id": "preferences",
        "children":
        [
        ]

    },

    {
        "caption": "Run",
        "command": "build"
    }
]
```

And for not messing with the default menu setting, I just had to create a folder (e.g. `RunMenu`) in `Data\Packages` and inside `RunMenu` I created a `Main.sublime-menu` file as above.